OLS estimator after standardization of the regressor
Consider a population in which two random variables, $y$ and $x$, satisfy the following relationship,
$$
y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+u,
$$
where $E[u \mid x]=0$. You wish to estimate the unknown coefficients $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, and to this end randomly sample $n \geq 1$ individuals from the population. For individual $i(=1, \ldots, n)$ in the sample, you observe $\left(y_i, x_i\right)$. Suppose that the $x_i$ 's do not all take the same value.
Instead of computing the usual OLS estimators, which we denote $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$, you decide to first transform the observed $x$ variable in the following way:
$$
\tilde{x}_i=\frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{\hat{\sigma}_x}, \quad i=1, \ldots ., n
$$
where $\bar{x}$ and $\hat{\sigma}_x^2$ are the sample mean and sample variance of $x$, respectively. You then estimate $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ by regressing $y$ onto $\tilde{x}$. Let $\tilde{\beta}_0$ and $\tilde{\beta}_1$ denote these alternative OLS estimators.
Question:
(a) Derive the probability limit of $\tilde{\beta}_0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
(b) Derive an expression of the sampling variance of $\tilde{\beta}_0, \operatorname{Var}\left(\tilde{\beta}_0 \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n\right)$.
(c) Propose adjustments to $\tilde{\beta}_0$ so that the adjusted version is consistent estimators of $\beta_0$.

Hi, welcome to economics.se. We require that users show us proof of an attempt at solving self-study question prior providing an answer
